# default SYSDATE used selectively based on user?

Tags: database, oracle

In Oracle I defined a table column with a default value of SYSDATE at shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE VK.BASERESULT
(
 ID                           NUMBER(22) NOT NULL,
 UPDATED_DATETIME             DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
 ...
)
```

The table is being persisted using Hibernate Object-to-relational mapper. What I'm finding is that when the user connecting to the database is the owner of the schema (VK), then the UPDATED_DATETIME column is correctly receiving the non-null value from SYSDATE when a row is inserted into the table. But when it is another authorized user who is doing the insert, there is an error saying
 ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("VK"."BASERESULT"."UPDATED_DATETIME")

Does SYSDATE enablement/usage require permissions for user? Which one?

Comment: Are you sure that is the problem? I doubt it. Rather, an INSERT like `insert into vk.baseresult(id) values (3)` will insert the default in the date column; but `insert into vk.baseresult values (3, null)` will fail in the way you described, regardless of users or permissions. Are you sure THIS is not how the different behavior is observed?

Comment: Are you sure they are both executing the same insert? Sounds like the owner is not including that column in the list, while the other user's session is specifying the column value as null. Which would stop the default applying. Another possibility is that the second user is actually seeing a view, and an instead-of trigger is causing the problem. How is hibernate connecting for both?

Comment: OK, I will check on this and report back. Thanks both for your comments.